# How to broadcast with distributed TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, distributed-tensorflow

I want to implement broadcast some values from chief to all workers with distributed TensorFlow like MPI's bcast:
https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#collective-communication

I guess [broadcast_send](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/eed8f6c0946cd229d9b749295dd02045271b066e/tensorflow/python/ops/collective_ops.py#L113-L120) or [tf.raw_ops.CollectiveBcastSend](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/raw_ops/CollectiveBcastSend?hl=en) is the operation, but I cloud not found any examples on TensorFlow official document.

Is there a good example to use such the row level distributed operations?